# Reformatting name / content pairs from grep in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm attempting to create a bash script that will grep a single file for two separate pieces of data, and print them to stdout.

So far this is what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /my/filePath/to/directory

APP=`grep -r --include "inputs.conf" "\[" | grep -oP '^[^\/]+'`
INPUT=`grep -r --include "inputs.conf" "\[" | grep -oP '\[[^\]]+'`

for i in $APP
do
{cd /opt/splunk/etc/deployment-apps
 INPUT=`grep -r --include "inputs.conf" "\[" | grep -oP '\[[^\]]+'`
 echo -n "$i | $INPUT"}

done
echo "";
exit
```

Which gives me an output printing the entire output of the first command (which is about 200 lines), then a `|`, then the other results from the second command. I was thinking I could create an array to do this, however I'm still learning bash.

This is an output example from the command without piping to grep:

```
TA-XA6x-Server/local/inputs.conf:[perfmon://Processor]
```

There are 200+ of these in a single execution, and I was looking to have the format be printed as something like this

```
app="TA-XA6x-Server/local/inputs.conf:" | input="[perfmon://Processor]"
```

There are essentially two pieces of information I'm attempting to stitch together:

1. the file path to the file
2. the contents of the file itself (the input)

Here is an example of the file path:

```
/opt/splunk/etc/deployment-apps/TA-XA6x-Server/local/inputs.conf
```

and this is an example of the inputs.conf file contents:

```
[perfmon://TCPv4]
```

Comment: Aside: All-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or system built-in tools. Your own variables should have lower-case names to avoid overwriting such variables by mistake (which can happen since shell and environment variables share a namespace); see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Comment: Use [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) to syntax-check your shell code.

Comment: Also, if writing a **bash** script, use `#!/bin/bash`. Using `#!/bin/sh` means you're writing a **POSIX sh** script, which is a different language with a different (more limited) syntax. Either fix the tag to be `sh` rather than bash, or fix the shebang on your script to be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: sorry. the output would be as such for all 200 instances:

`app="TA-XA6x-Server/local/inputs.conf:" | input="[perfmon://Processor]"`

There are two grep statements because I thought that was the best way to approach it. Very probable this isn't.. i'm still pretty green.

Comment: Output in which variable, `INPUT` or `APP`? Why do you have both?

Comment: Sure, there are two pieces i'm attempting to stitch together:

1. the file path to the file
2. the contents of the file

Comment: See BashFAQ #1, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, for the technique used in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy, mostly-working-ish approach is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read -r name content; do
  printf 'app="%s" | input="%s"\n' "$name" "$content"
done < <(grep -r --include "inputs.conf" "\[")
```

---

If you need to work reliably with all possible filenames (including names with colons or newlines) and have GNU grep available, consider the `--null` argument to `grep` and adjusting the `read` usage appropriately:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' name && IFS= read -r content; do
  printf 'app="%s" | input="%s"\n' "$name" "$content"
done < <(grep -r --null --include "inputs.conf" "\[")
```